# How to add net.tcp protocol support for IIS Express used by Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, visual-studio, iis

I'm using the default configuration of Visual Studio to host my wcf service in a development scenario. I want to add a net.tcp endpoint, but I always get an error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-faq) FAQ, this functionality is not available in IIS Express:

Here's the extract of the relevant question from the FAQ:

> Q: Does IIS Express support non-HTTP protocols such as net.tcp or MSMQ?
>
> A: No. IIS Express only supports HTTP and HTTPS as its protocol.

For TCP bindings, you might have to create your own service host (e.g. if it's just for testing or similar, perhaps in a console application). Either that or go with the [full](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725762.aspx) IIS install (sorry, I've assumed you're on Win7) and deploy your application there.