# Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Base address schemes are [http]

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I have this configuration for my WCF service which runs on IIS Express port number 50187. The service is hosted on IIS Express of Visual Studio 2017:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="QCConsumerBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="50000000" maxBufferPoolSize="5242880" maxReceivedMessageSize="50000000" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="QCWCFService.QCService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="QCConsumerBinding" contract="QCWCFService.IQCService" />
      </service>
      <service name="QCWCFService.QCFinalService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="QCConsumerBinding" contract="QCWCFService.IQCFinalService" />
      </service>

      <service name="QCWCFService.CalibrationService">
        <endpoint address="service" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="QCWCFService.ICalibrationService" />
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="QCWCFService.ICalibrationService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8080/CalibrationService" />
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8081/CalibrationService" />
          </baseAddresses>

        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>          
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="http" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

But when I try to run the service it gives this exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].
```

While I have another application with the same configuration for Dual Http Binding which works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, The IIS express doesn’t support `Net.tcp` protocol.
The service endpoint with `Nettcpbinding` requires a base address based on `NetTcp` protocol.

```
<endpoint address="service" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="QCWCFService.ICalibrationService" />
```

Although we provide a `Nettcp` base address by using the `Host Section`, It won’t work. This is due to the fact IIS express use self-configuration to provide a base address to run the current project. The configuration of IIS express usually located in the .vs folder of the current Solution, called `applicationhost.config`
[image]
If we run this project in a console application with this configuration, it will work. Thereby we should provide one base address with Nettcp protocol. This can be completed in IIS.
1. Enable windows feature for `net.tcp` protocol.
[image]
2. Add `Net.tcp` support on the website.
[image]
3. Add `net.tcp` protocol in `site binding module`.
[image]
Please refer to the below for details of adding `net.tcp` protocol to a website.
[WCF ContractFilter Mismatch when enabling Reliable Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58555953/wcf-contractfilter-mismatch-when-enabling-reliable-session/58588736#58588736)
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. but why my other project with similar configuration is working on IIS Express?

Comment: Maybe I should search how to enable nettcp protocol on IIS Express. Anyhow the service works on IIS. Thank you very much. You saved my time.

Comment: After a search on the internet, I found IIS express doesn't support Nettcp protocol. Can you consume the service with a Nettcp address? this indicates whether it works on Net.tcp.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15838792/how-to-add-net-tcp-protocol-support-for-iis-express-used-by-visual-studio

Comment: My fault. I cannot consume the service. It works just on IIS.

Comment: It doesn't matter, have a nice day.