# Issue with Listening at an Endpoint connecting to WCF from net.tcp protocol

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, endpoint, net.tcp

This weird Error was appearing from one day before posting this post. Previously it was working fine, but not now.

At one movement restarting the system, the error disappears and able to access the application.

and after again rebooting the system the error begins to appear without knowing the root cause.

Enabled Protocols: `net.tcp,http`

I could able to browse the below link

- http://localhost/TAServices/AuthenticationManager.svc
- http://username.domainname.com/TAServices/AuthenticationManager.svc?wsdl
- http://username.domainname.com/TAServices/AuthenticationManager.svc?singleWsdl

Here is the below snippet which causes an exception

```
objCheckUserLoginResponse = AuthenticationManagerClient.Check(objCheckUserLoginRequest, objCustomer);
```

**Exception:**

```
The message could not be dispatched because the service at the endpoint address 'net.tcp://localhost/TAServices/AuthenticationManager.svc' is unavailable for the protocol of the address. 
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: The message could not be dispatched because the service at the endpoint address 'net.tcp://localhost/TAServices/AuthenticationManager.svc' is unavailable for the protocol of the address.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionUpgradeHelper.DecodeFramingFault(ClientFramingDecoder decoder, IConnection connection, Uri via, String contentType, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamedFramingRequestChannel.SendPreamble(IConnection connection, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper, ClientFramingDecoder decoder, SecurityMessageProperty& remoteSecurity)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamedFramingRequestChannel.StreamedConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection connection, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamedFramingRequestChannel.StreamedFramingRequest.SendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at TA.ServiceProxy.AuthenticationManager.IAuthenticationManager.Check(CheckUserLoginRequest1 request)
   at TA.ServiceProxy.AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationManagerClient.TA.ServiceProxy.AuthenticationManager.IAuthenticationManager.Check(CheckUserLoginRequest1 request) in D:\2017_TFS\TestandAssessment\Dev\Manifest\TestPrepAdmin\ServiceProxy\Service References\AuthenticationManager\Reference.cs:line 3370
   at TA.ServiceProxy.AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationManagerClient.Check(CheckUserLoginRequest Request, Customer Customer) in D:\2017_TFS\TestandAssessment\Dev\Manifest\TestPrepAdmin\ServiceProxy\Service References\AuthenticationManager\Reference.cs:line 3377
   at TA.UIFrameWork.AuthenticationManagement.AuthenticateUser(CheckUserLoginRequest objCheckUserLoginRequest) in D:\2017_TFS\TestandAssessment\Dev\Manifest\TestPrepAdmin\UIFrameWork\Authentication\AuthenticationManagement.cs:line 19
 T: 2020-05-09 12:19:52,242 |L: INFO |TH: 8 |L: Utilities.PageBase |MSG: 
SessionID:  Method: LoadLanguages
Info: Page: Login.aspx Method: LoadLanguages Enters
```

AuthenticationManagement.cs

```
using TA.ServiceProxy.AuthenticationManager;
using System;

namespace TA.UIFrameWork
{
    public class AuthenticationManagement
    {
        public CheckUserLoginResponse AuthenticateUser(CheckUserLoginRequest objCheckUserLoginRequest)
        {
            Customer objCustomer;
            CheckUserLoginResponse objCheckUserLoginResponse = null;
            try
            {
                objCustomer = new Customer();
                objCustomer.CustomerName = "ABC";
                objCustomer.CultureInfo = "English";
                AuthenticationManagerClient AuthenticationManagerClient = new AuthenticationManagerClient();
                AuthenticationManagerClient.Open();
                objCheckUserLoginResponse = AuthenticationManagerClient.Check(objCheckUserLoginRequest, objCustomer);
                AuthenticationManagerClient.Close();
                AuthenticationManagerClient = null;
                objCustomer = null;
                objCheckUserLoginRequest = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LoggingFramework.log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
            }
            return objCheckUserLoginResponse;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data" />
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    <section name="dns" type="System.Configuration.NameValueFileSectionHandler" />
  </configSections>
  <dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="LocalSqlServer" />
  <dns file="dns.config" />
  <system.web>
    <!-- Web Part -->
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/MVCFramework" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile enabled="true" defaultProvider="TableProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="TableProfileProvider" type="Microsoft.Samples.SqlTableProfileProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" table="aspnet_Profile" applicationName="/MVCFramework" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <!-- End Web Part -->

    <pages validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false" enableViewStateMac="false" maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <controls>
        <add namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <customErrors mode="Off">
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="Status.aspx" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="Status.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true">
    </httpCookies>
    <trace enabled="false" localOnly="true">
    </trace>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="220000" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="false" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only  
            during development.
        -->
    <compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="c#" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="6000" cookieless="UseCookies">
    </sessionState>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?" />
    </authorization>

    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false" />
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1024000000"></requestLimits>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      <add name="QueryStringValidation" type="Presentation.Utilities.QueryStringValidation" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.3.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Framework" closeTimeout="00:50:00" openTimeout="00:50:00" receiveTimeout="00:50:00" sendTimeout="00:50:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="999999999" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="999999999" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="999999999" maxArrayLength="999999999" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_Framework" closeTimeout="00:50:00" openTimeout="00:50:00" receiveTimeout="00:50:00" sendTimeout="00:51:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Streamed" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="999999999" maxBufferSize="999999999" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="999999999">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="999999999" maxArrayLength="999999999" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:50:00" enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
   <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/TAServices/AccountManager.svc" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_Framework" contract="AccountManager.IAccountManager" name="NetTcpBinding_Framework" />
  </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ClientBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="10000000" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <location path="Common">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="5000000" />
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

Without knowing the cause I was not able to do anything.
Please suggest in resolving `EndpointNotFoundException` issue wrt to code or from windows 10 (1903)

Comment: Where you have configured the endpoints of your service?I didn't saw in config file

Answer (score 11):

I had solved this issue by releasing `OneApp.IGCC.WinService.exe` which had occupied the port `808` after Intel® Graphics Driver update was initiated. But it sounds weird, so check whether `SMSvcHost.exe` is listing to `808` port.

```
C:\Windows\system32>netstat -ano | find "808"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:808            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4356
  TCP    [::]:808               [::]:0                 LISTENING       4356

C:\Windows\system32>tasklist | find "5156"
SMSvcHost.exe                 5156 Services                   0      5,604 K
```

If you find that process name other than `SMSvcHost.exe` listed such as `OneApp.IGCC.WinService.ex` or with some other name, then continue to follow these steps, otherwise stop here.

So in my case, process by name `OneApp.IGCC.WinService.ex` has occupied with port `808` having an unique Process ID as `5068`
Execute the command `TASKKILL /F /PID <ProcessId>` from elevated prompt.

```
C:\Windows\system32>netstat -ano | find "808"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:808            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       5068
  TCP    [::]:808               [::]:0                 LISTENING       5068

C:\Windows\system32>tasklist | find "5068"
OneApp.IGCC.WinService.ex     5068 Services                   0     36,632 K

C:\Windows\system32>taskkill /F /PID 5068
SUCCESS: The process with PID 5068 has been terminated.

C:\Windows\system32>netstat -ano | find "808"


C:\Windows\system32>
```

Then Restart the `Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service` from `services.msc`

Even after rebooting the system `OneApp.IGCC.WinService.exe` will override the `SMSvcHost.exe` by listening to `808` port. So Disable running of `Intel(R) Graphics Command Center Service (C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\igcc_dch.inf_amd64_26b207b939eae50e)` from `services.msc`

Comment: Does setting Startup option to Automatic (Delayed Start) helps also?

Comment: I met this issue too. Have you tried to set Startup option to Delay Start, does that help?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you host the WCF service project in IIS and try to make it work over `HTTP` and `Nettcp`. In order to make it work over NetTcp protocol, we should enable certain Window features and NetTcp binding in the IIS site binding module. Also, we are supposed to configure a service endpoint with Nettcpbinding, which is not set up in your `Webconfig` file.
Please consider replacing the `System.servicemodel` section with the below configuration.

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
                <endpoint address="service1" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" ></endpoint>
                <endpoint address="service2" binding="netTcpBinding"  contract="WcfService1.IService1"></endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
            </service>
        </services>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding>
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding>
                    <security mode="None"></security>
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

In order to support Net.tcp protocol in IIS, please enable following windows feature.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/15e3G.png]
Subsequently, Add Net.tcp support on the website.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LM9jv.png]
Finally, add a site binding with net.tcp protocol. Note,808 is the default port for net.tcp protocol. Do not use the port number already used by another website.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yVz4.png]
Please refer to below link.
[Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Base address schemes are [http]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60278423/could-not-find-a-base-address-that-matches-scheme-net-tcp-for-the-endpoint-with/60293744#60293744)
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.